# Factor matrix ${\bf A}$ into the product ${\bf B}{\bf C}$ where ${\bf C}$ has no negative entries and ${\bf B}$ has few non-zero entries

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, nonnegative-matrices

*This is a more carefully worded version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719656/factor-a-square-matrix-bf-a-into-product-bf-b-bf-c-where-bf-c) question, here tailored to professional mathematicians.*

Consider a matrix ${\bf A}\in{\bf M}_{n\times n}({\mathbb R})$ with possibly positive, negative and zero-valued entries and ${\rm Det}[{\bf A}] \neq 0$.

> Is there an algorithm to write ${\bf A}$ as a product of two matrices
>   ${\bf B}{\bf C}$ where ${\bf B} \in{\bf M}_{n\times n}({\mathbb R})$ and ${\bf C} \in{\bf M}_{n\times n}({\mathbb R}_\ge)$ in which ${\bf B}$ has the maximum number of $0$
>   entries (i.e., is sparse) and all the entries of ${\bf C}$ are
>   non-negative?  Again, the cost metric is the number of non-zero
>   entries in ${\bf B}$.

**Example**

Suppose ${\bf A} = \left( { \ \ 1\ \ \ \ 2 \atop -6\ -8} \right)$.

Here are three factorizations, ${\bf B}{\bf C}$, with their associated costs.

- $\left( { \ \ 1\ \ \ \ \ 2 \atop -6\ -8} \right)\left( {1\ \ \ \ 0 \atop 0\ \ \ \ 1} \right)$,  Cost = $4$
- $\left( {0\ \ \ \ \ 2 \atop 1\ \ \ \ -14} \right)\left( {1\ \ \ \ \ \ 6 \atop 1/2\ \ \ \ 1} \right)$,  Cost = $3$
- $\left( {1\ \ \ \ \ 0 \atop 0\ \ \ \ -2} \right)\left( {1\ \ \ \ \ 2 \atop 3\ \ \ \ \ 4} \right)$,  Cost = $2$

I do not need an algorithm to find a *unique* decomposition, just a principled method for finding at least one having minimum cost.

As far as I know, despite immense work on matrix factorization, this precise problem has never been solved.  (*Polar decomposition*, *Cholesky decomposition*, *LUD decomposition*, *Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization* and *Sparse matrix approximation* are not quite appropriate.)

**Motivation**

The general computational task is to perform the linear operation ${\bf A}{\bf x}$, where ${\bf A}$ has the conditions listed above and ${\bf x}$ is an $n$-dimensional real-valued vector of non-negative entries.  The overall computational task can be split into two linear systems.  The first system can perform ${\bf C}{\bf x}$ at extremely low computational cost (assume zero cost), but the entries of ${\bf C}$ must be non-negative.  The second system can perform ${\bf B}{\bf y}$ (where ${\bf y} = {\bf C}{\bf x}$) and the entries of ${\bf B}$ can be positive or negative or zero but there is a unit cost for each non-zero entry of ${\bf B}$.

We seek to split the overall computation of ${\bf A}{\bf x}$ into the two systems to minimize the overall computational cost.

Comment: First line. "possibly positive and negative" -- so you don't allow zero? And "full rank" doesn't mean "has distinct eigenvalues" usually -- do you mean "has distinct eigenvalues" or "has full rank in the standard sense" (i.e. non-zero determinant)? And your link doesn't work. And here's an algorithm -- set $B=A$ times the inverse of some random invertible matrix $C$ with positive entries that you choose before you were even told $B$, if $A$ doesn't have non-negative entries, and $B=I$ and $C=A$ otherwise.

Comment: znt  I've clarified your questions.  But as I stated explicitly "Of course, the trivial solution ${\bf B} = {\bf A}$ and ${\bf C} = {\bf I}$ (the identity matrix) will yield such a factorization" and then went on to state the conditions for a non-trivial solution.

Comment: How about if you wait on the MSE question for a few days? Also, your link to it is faulty, there are some extraneous characters before the http. I tried to fix it with no luck http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719656/factor-a-square-matrix-bf-a-into-product-bf-b-bf-c-where-bf-c

Comment: My algorithm satisfies your conditions as far as I can see.

Comment: You don't give enough information to make this a rigorous maths question. You need to tell us exact running times for the two systems before someone can minimise the overall computational cost. And presumably you are well aware that a gazillion man-hours have already gone into the problem of multiplying a matrix by a vector whilst minimising the overall computational cost. Are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: znt  My example shows, I believe, that your algorithm does not satisfy the problem conditions.

Comment: Yes, the question looks better now. Good luck with it!

Comment: My goodness:  Why the problem downvote?!  This seems like a well-posed, interesting, non-trivial problem.  I won't go into the application of this problem, but let me merely say solving this problem will provide a foundation for an entire class of scientific and technological research.

Comment: Gerry Myerson:  (Thanks for catching a typo... now fixed.)  The cost of ${\bf C}$ is zero (so long as its entries are non-negative), and the cost of ${\bf B}$ is the total count of its non-zero entries.  In short, the "${\bf C}$" process is "free."

Comment: If you want to be certain that I will see a comment meant for me, David, you have to write @Gerry.

Comment: Can you modify your system to add (subtract) two matrices? For then you could represent A as G-H where G and H have all positive entries.  Gerhard "Wants Out Of The Box" Paseman, 2016.03.31.

Comment: @GerardPasemen:  Alas, no.  (That would be a different, possibly valuable, algorithm under somewhat different application circumstances.)

Comment: A computationally intractable formulation is: $\min \|A-BC\|_F$ subject to $\|B\|_0 \le \delta, C \ge 0$. Performing alternating minimization over $B$ and $C$ can help obtain a reasonable solution. You can replace $\|B\|_0 \le \delta$ by a sparsity promoting convex constraint such as $\|B\|_1 \le \delta'$. The problem as stated is intractable.

Comment: Thanks @Suvrit, but I don't see from your comment why the problem is intractable.  Perhaps the optimization is non-convex, and there may be no principled method for knowing $\delta$, but those facts alone don't necessarily imply the problem is intractable, does it?

Comment: You could alternatively write it as: $\min\|B\|_0$ s.t. $A=BC$ and $C \ge 0$ which appears intractable due to the $\ell_0$-cost function, and most likely one should be able to reduce some standard hard problem to this one.

Comment: Why optically must $C$ be $n \times n$? Why not $2n \times n$, which would make the problem trivial?

Comment: Do you really want to minimize the number of entries of $B$, or are you fine finding a solution where the number of entries of $B$ is reasonably low? For instance, they could be within a constant of optimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $v_1, \dots, v_n$ denote the rows of $A$.

Let $u$ be a vector with all positive entries that is not a linear combination of $v_2, \dots, v_n$. Then we may write $v_1 = c u + a_2 v_2 + \dots a_n v_n$ for some scalars $c, a_2, \dots, a_n$.

Now choose $\epsilon$ small enough that for all $j$ from $2$ to $n$, $u + \epsilon \sum_{i=2}^j a_i v_i$ has all positive entries.

Let $C$ be the matrix with rows $u + \epsilon \sum_{i=2}^j a_i v_i$ for $j$ from $1$ to $n$.  Then by construction $C$ has all positive entries.

Each vector $v_i$ can be written as a linear combination of two rows of $C$. For $v_i$ this is by subtracting two adjacent rows and dividing by $\epsilon$, and for $v_1$ it is $c-1/\epsilon$ times the first row plus $1/\epsilon$ times the last row.

We conclude that there is a sparse matrix $B$ with $2n$ entries such that $BC = A$.

This is optimal assuming each of the $v_i$ has both positive and negative entries, as the corresponding row of $B$ must have both positive and negative entries and hence at least $2$ entries.  If $A$ has any rows that are either non-negative or non-positive, then this algorithm might not be optimal, as the example in the original question shows.  However, this algorithm produces matrices where $BC$ is very sensitive to slight changes in $C$ and thus may be unsuitable for practical applications.

Comment: Thanks, @Will Shawn.  Let me try coding this up and seeing if it works on a few simple cases and how sensitive it might be to changes in entries to ${\bf C}$.  (This will take a two or three days...)

Comment: Will Shawn (@Will Shawn):  Your third line should be $\nu_1 = cu + a_2 \nu_2 + \ldots a_n \nu_n$.  Right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Right.

Comment: And the $2n$ entries need not be optimal, as my simple example shows... right?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes. Of course it is off by a factor of at most $2$. I thought a simple modification of my argument gives the optimum but that turns out not to be the case.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, @Will Sawin, because it is a step in the right direction.  However, there are a number of very quick improvements that I've found.  For instance, if any row $i$ in ${\bf A}$ has only non-negative entries, then a single $+1$ in the $i,i$ entry of ${\bf B}$ with the $i$ row of ${\bf C}$ set to $i$ row of ${\bf A}$ reduces the cost.  Likewise if the row of ${\bf A}$ has a row with non-positive entries, simply set the $i,i$ entry of ${\bf B}$ to $-1$, and so forth.  I must say, I'm surprised such factorization (apparently) doesn't appear in the scholarly literature.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I thought of those too. If that improvement always worked, then it is easy to prove that it gives the optimal method. However, then the method requires me to write $v_1$ as a linear combination of an all positive vector $u$ and a subset  of the $v_2,\dots,v_n$ - the subset consisting of vectors that have both positive and negative entries. Unfortunately it's not obvious that this is possible.

Comment: If ${\bf A}$ has non-vanishing determinant, then its $n$ eigenvectors span an $n$-dimensional space.  Once the $k$ non-negative or non-positive mutually independent rows have been eliminated, the remaining $n-k$ rows still be mutually independent *may* be spannable by $n-k$ non-negative or non-positive rows.  If not, what condition upon ${\bf A}$ will ensure that it can so be spanned.

Answer (score 1):

I find it curious that addition of two vectors can't be used in your system, but that matrix multiplication of a vector by a positive matrix is so cheap.  In any case, I doubt that you will be able to find a factorization with minimal cost for B quickly.

Certain cases can be handled cheaply: Find elementary row operations R on A that produce C, and let BR=I and RA=C.  This will handle all cases where A has a row with all entries nonzero and of the same sign.  B will have a cost of at most 2n-1, and at least n+r (which is minimum) with r the number of rows of A that have both positive and negative entries.

For the general case, you could try to find a small linear combination of rows of A which produces a positive row.  I have not worked out the details, but I would hope that if you found s rows to do that, you could combine it with the above to produce a B with cost bounded by sn+n.  However, finding a small set of s rows should be reducible to some NP-hard problems in matrix algebra/combinatorics.  So I am not hopeful for a quick general algorithm.

Gerhard "Subtracting Vectors Would Help Much" Paseman, 2016.03.31.

Comment: Thanks.  The application area involves optics, in which a particular class of optical devices can perform a linear operation.  "Addition" of vectors would involve shining extra light, which here is impossible; "subtraction" of vectors is very hard and would involve rejecting light, which would reduce signal and is hence undesirable.  (An optical filter *multiplies* the values in the light by a number < 1.0.)  I don't understand your answer, though, because it relies on steps that "produce C," but C is unknown.

Comment: If for example A has the first row all positive entries, and say only negative entries in the second and third rows, then an elementary matrix R which adds a large multiple of the first row to each of the second and third rows produces a C (=RA) which has all positive entries.  R has n+2 nonzero entries and because of how I did it B will also have n+2 nonzero entries.  The only way to improve on this is if the second or third rows had no positive entries, in which case addition by the first row is not needed. Gerhard "Hopefully You Get The Picture" Paseman, 2016.03.31.

Comment: If you could adapt your system to have B factored into DE, then E could cost n+s and D could cost 2n-1.  Maybe this would work?  Gerhard "Likes Adding Even More Filters" Paseman, 2016.03.31.

Comment: Multiple linear matrices is of course fine, so long as the right-most (first to operate on ${\bf x}$) has only non-negative entries.  In short, ${\bf S}{\bf T}{\bf U}{\bf W}{\bf C} = {\bf B}^\prime {\bf C}$ is of course fine.  The cost remains the non-zero entries in ${\bf B}^\prime$, though.

Comment: Then you can do it with two matrices with a cost of under 2n for each matrix.  Find a linear combination of rows which has coefficients of the same sign, then add the proper multiple of this to all rows that need it.  C will be positive, B will invert the adding and R will invert the linear combination. A=RBC.  However, RB may have more than 4n nonzero entries. Gerhard "At Least Has Upper Bound" Paseman, 2016.03.31.